# Restart individual application in apache+passenger on ubuntu server

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, deployment, phusion-passenger

I have multiple ruby on rails applications on the server(Apache + passenger ) using RailsbaseURI.

When new applications are deployed, apache is configured to reload which reads the new configuration in apache.conf and the new url 
for app becomes active.

I was looking for options where individual apps can be restarted using some socket. Can anyone refer me some pointers for that implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this. I'd be happy to be corrected, but I think this is just a fault of apache and passenger. (Could also explain why no one commented on this)

I actually had to go to extreme measure to get around this (every time I was updating a site on my host, I had to restart all the apps), so I moved to nginx and unicorn. Unicorn allows the application to be bound to unix sockets, and nginx reads nicely from those sockets.

There are numerous [guides](http://mojoware.com/posts/upgrading-apache-to-nginx-passenger-to-unicorn) for this migration.